# How to prevent resetting the OpenFileDialog filter after inserting an asterisk symbol?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

In my filedialog I've set a filter. In this case `*.doc|*.docx`.

When the user inserts the asterisk symbol in the 'File name' textbox and hits ENTER the filter is being reset showing all the files.

How can I prevent this?

[image]

Comment: The user stays in control of the dialog, the filter is just meant to help cut down the number of displayed files.  It is still your job to ensure that the proper file gets selected.  Including files that have a .doc extension but are not actually Word files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the dialog. Only thing you can do is to check the file extension that user has chosen. If the extension is not .doc or .docx, you could reopen the dialog.

Here is function that might be helpful for you:

```
string ext = Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialog.FileName);
```

This will return only the extension of the file.